# Manhattan layout algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, layout, graph-theory, prefuse

I am looking for any of the following (in order of preference):

- A Manhattan layout [EdgeRenderer](https://web.archive.org/web/20090401000000/http://prefuse.org/doc/api/prefuse/render/EdgeRenderer.html) for [prefuse](https://web.archive.org/web/20090401000000/http://prefuse.org/).
- A Manhattan [layout](https://web.archive.org/web/20090401000000/http://prefuse.org/doc/api/prefuse/action/layout/Layout.html) for prefuse.
- An algorithm to produce [Manhattan layouts](http://www.aisee.com/graph_of_the_month/syntax3.gif) for hierarchical, directed acyclic graphs.
- An [organizational chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organizational_chart) implementation.

Sample implementations include:

- [NodeLinkTreeLayout](https://web.archive.org/web/20090401000000/http://prefuse.org/doc/api/prefuse/action/layout/graph/NodeLinkTreeLayout.html) (for prefuse) is close, but edge style is not orthogonal.
- [Easy Graph for Perl](http://bloodgate.com/perl/graph/manual/)
- [Graphical JavaScript Tree](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/scripting/graphic_javascript_tree.aspx)

Do you know where to find something along those lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use prefuse to create an EdgeRenderer subclass:

```
/**
 * Responsible for drawing orthogonal edges between two nodes.
 */
public class OrthogonalEdgeRenderer
  extends EdgeRenderer {
  /**
   * Creates a new edge renderer with a given arrowType. The edgeType is
   * ignored -- the edges are drawn orthogonally, as per the responsibility
   * of this class. The arrowType is one of the Constants.EDGE_ARROW_* values.
   *
   * @param edgeType Ignored.
   * @param arrowType One of Constants.EDGE_ARROW_*.
   * @see prefuse.Constants
   */
  public OrthogonalEdgeRenderer( int edgeType, int arrowType ) {
    super( edgeType, arrowType );
  }

  /**
   * Creates a new instance with no arrow head.
   */
  public OrthogonalEdgeRenderer() {
    this( Constants.EDGE_TYPE_LINE, Constants.EDGE_ARROW_NONE );
  }

  /**
   * Creates an orthogonal shape (an edge) to draw between two nodes.
   *
   * @param vi The visual item with start and end points.
   * @return The shape to draw between the nodes for this edge.
   */
  protected Shape getRawShape( VisualItem vi ) {
    Path2D.Double result = new Path2D.Double();

    if( vi instanceof EdgeItem ) {
      EdgeItem ei = ( EdgeItem )vi;

      double sx = ei.getSourceItem().getX();
      double sy = ei.getSourceItem().getY();
      double tx = ei.getTargetItem().getX();
      double ty = ei.getTargetItem().getY();

      double midy = ( sy + ty ) / 2;

      if( midy != sy && midy != ty ) {
        result.moveTo( sx, sy );
        result.lineTo( sx, midy );
        result.lineTo( tx, midy );
        result.lineTo( tx, ty );
      }
    }

    return result;
  }
}
```